# Webpage scroll issue iOS

Tags: ios, swift, web, uiwebview

Hi Im loading a webpage in web view in iOS.
Webpage inside the web view doesn't scroll. Webview only bounces. 
I tried giving this but didnt work
self.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;

Comment: Bouncing should not prevent scrolling. How did you set the size of webView's frame? If the web page you are loading is taller than the frame's height, it should scroll naturally without any kind of customization needed.

Comment: Height of webpage is decided by html. Webview has normal constraints to fit full screen. Content size is what matters rite. how can I debug the issue

Comment: Are you sure this is not an issue with the web page you're trying to load? Have you tried with other ones? Webviews manage their content size automatically. Would be nice and easier if you show your code.

Comment: WEbview size is default. Not sure why the page rendering is getting delayed. This is the code i have used.
self.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;  self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

Comment: May need the complete code to help you here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example